# How to show image in gridview with SQLite using glide library?

Tags: java, android, image, sqlite, android-glide

I have an SQLite database to save an image. I want to show the image to grid view and I want to use glide library, but I don't know how to use it

```
  public Bitmap bitmap (byte[] byteImage){
    byte[] outImage = byteImage;
    Bitmap image ;
    if (outImage != null){
        ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outImage);
        image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
    }else {
        image= null;
    }
    return image;
}
```

And this

```
 public byte[] getImageByte(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte imageInByte[]=null;
    if(bitmap!=null) {
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream);
        imageInByte=stream.toByteArray();
    }
    return imageInByte;
}
```

And this in my adapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView==null){

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_produk, null);

        holder.txtNama = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvnmproduk);
        holder.txtHarga = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvharga);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgproduk);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    ModelProduk modelProduk = produklist.get(position);

    holder.txtNama.setText(modelProduk.get_nama());
    holder.txtHarga.setText(Integer.toString(modelProduk.get_harga()));

    /*byte[] produkimage = modelProduk.get_gambar();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(produkimage, 0 , produkimage.length);*/
    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap(modelProduk.get_gambar()));


    return convertView;
```

I watch in every tutorial it must written

```
Glide.with()
            .load()
            .into();
```

but I don't know where to put that code

Comment: refer this link https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-getting-started

Answer (score 2):

**Use this**

```
Glide.with(mContext).load(imgUrl)
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(imageView);
```

Comment: In your adapter class

Comment: don't use this line holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap(modelProduk.get_gambar()));

Comment: I try it and when i run the apps, the apps not showing the image. what should i do?

Comment: first u try one image

Comment: thank you, finally my apps work! . i forgot to call the bitmap method to show the image

Comment: ha ha super nice